# should pulled API data be stored inside a database

Tags: sql, json, django, database, api

I am creating my own django project to show stats of fantasy premier league players (FPL) where i use API data from another website.

In my own website i want users to be able to search and query these players based on certain attributes such as goals scored, minutes played etc...

Am i best to store these values inside my own database to make the querying process easier and more efficient OR just filter out certain players from the API data in the json format OR do a combination of both methods

Comment: you need to keep updating data in your own database. it will be useful when you need to perform other operations as well. also you can do caching as well for data fetched from API

Answer (score 0):

If the FPL API has a search endpoint you could just call that endpoint with the query your users search with.

Storing the values in your own database would mean you'd then have duplicated data, since you are consuming an external API and also have a database with the same data. This goes against single source of truth.

If the external API does not have a search endpoint then I'd recommend creating your own DB and consuming your DB for all endpoints, not just search.